# How to pass fields from parent to sublist in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a field variable that I get from a JavaBean as follows in my main report view:

```
<field name="username" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[username]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Now I also have a `sublist` for some nested objects, but the sublist should also have access to the `username`.
The following does not work:

```
<subDataset name="sublist">
    <field name="username" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$F{username}]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
```

This fails as there is no field `username` defined within the sublist itself. How can I tell `JasperReports` to look into the parent when resolving the parameter in the sublist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing it as a parameter.

```
<datasetRun subDataset="sublist">
    <datasetParameter name="username">
        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{username}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
    </datasetParameter>
</datasetRun>
```

Comment: You're great. Glad that it's easy when you know how.